# Animated Texture Over all the Existing Materials

Tags: shaders

I'm wondering if there is an option or a possibility to make a material that overlays or combines  all the existing materials without having to assign the whole UV map to it because if I do it will disconnect my already made materials from its UV maps. My goal is: I'm trying to make a reveal animation of the hoodie, from completely transparent to fully visible by using some type of texture in my case magic texture with colorramp. Currently this reveal animation is on the front of the hoodie and front part(UV's) are assigned to this material. **How do I add this animation to the whole hoodie?** with keeping the existing materials assigned to its UV's. [image]

How do I assign this setup of nodes that are in the white box to the whole hoodie without disturbing the rest of the materials? is there a way to do so?

Comment: Hello do you have a video that shows what you want? or a storyboard?

Comment: @moonboots Hey, sure here is a link [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17mVRwgRD376Pp6avIrKwsYtb4dwi6Zdz?usp=sharing] I would like this reveal effect to affect the whole hoodie, according to my mains posts description